# Change the volume of a wav file in python

Tags: python, audio, wav, volume, wave

I have a 2 seconds 16bit single channel 8khz wav file and I need to change its volume.

It should be quite straightforward, because changing the volume is the same as changing the amplitude of the signal, and I just need to attenuate it, that is to multiply it for a number between 0 and 1. But it doesn't work: the new sound is lower but VERY full of noise. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
import wave, numpy, struct

# Open
w = wave.open("input.wav","rb")
p = w.getparams()
f = p[3] # number of frames
s = w.readframes(f)
w.close()

# Edit
s = numpy.fromstring(s, numpy.int16) * 5 / 10  # half amplitude
s = struct.pack('h'*len(s), *s)

# Save
w = wave.open("output.wav","wb")
w.setparams(p)
w.writeframes(s)
w.close()
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: Why are you using `* 5 / 10` instead of `/ 2`?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that the `* 5` part is clipping and overflowing.

Comment: Are you reading the file in the correct endianness? [WAV files are little-endian.](http://web.archive.org/web/19991115123323/http://www.borg.com/~jglatt/tech/wave.htm) Using the other endian will halve the sample and add a LOT of noise.

Comment: Oh my...!! Sorry for posting that... The response was too easy.

By doing this:

    s = numpy.fromstring(s, numpy.int16) * 5 / 10  # half amplitude

The signal is saturated, because I multiplied the integers before dividing them.

A solution:

    s = numpy.fromstring(s, numpy.int16) / 10 * 5  # half amplitude

Be careful, this does NOT work as the division results zero:

    s = numpy.fromstring(s, numpy.int16) * (5 / 10)  # half amplitude

I keep it here in case it helps someone else.

Comment: Jan, because they are supposed to be vars: 5 is desired volume and 10 is original volume.

Comment: You should post your comment as an answer and accept it when possible (+24h IIRC)

Comment: Thank you Jan, but stackoverflow lets me wait for another 7 hours before I can post an answer... :)

Comment: @JanDvorak Since you found the problem, it would be fair if you posted an answer and the OP accepted it. A full solution would probably include multiplying with `float(desired_volume) / float(orig_volume)`.

Comment: @user4815162342 Too bad I'm not fluent in python. I didn't even know if python didn't use float types for everything.

Comment: Another thing: the `*` operator in `struct.pack('h', *s)` line converts the entire numpy array into a tuple of int objects. This is potentially very inefficient—you should use `s.tostring` instead, which will efficiently create a string directly from the array contents.

Comment: If it's scaled by a float, just using `tostring` will give the wrong result. But instead you could do `s = (s * (desired/original)).astype(numpy.int16).tostring()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you can see in the comments of the question, there are several solutions, some more efficient.

The problem was immediately detected by Jan Dvorak ("the * 5 part is clipping and overflowing") and the straightforward solution was:

```
s = numpy.fromstring(s, numpy.int16) / 10 * 5
```

In this case, this solution was perfect for me, just good enough.

Thank you all folks!

Answer (score 23):

I wrote a [library to simplify this type of thing](http://pydub.com)

You can do that like so:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

song = AudioSegment.from_wav("never_gonna_give_you_up.wav")

# reduce volume by 10 dB
song_10_db_quieter = song - 10

# but let's make him *very* quiet
song = song - 36

# save the output
song.export("quieter.wav", "wav")
```

Comment: Could you attenuate Mr. Astley by 36dB instead?

Comment: @msw sure that would be `song = song - 36`

Answer (score 5):

This can be done with the `audioop` module in Python's standard library.
This way, no dependencies like `pydub` or `numpy` are needed.

```py
import wave, audioop

factor = 0.5

with wave.open('input.wav', 'rb') as wav:
    p = wav.getparams()
    with wave.open('output.wav', 'wb') as audio:
        audio.setparams(p)
        frames = wav.readframes(p.nframes)
        audio.writeframesraw( audioop.mul(frames, p.sampwidth, factor))
```

Comment: This is basically what pydub does under the hood

Answer (score 2):

The code which makes sound louder plus filter low and high frequencies

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

audio_file = "first.mp3"

song = AudioSegment.from_mp3(audio_file)

new = song.low_pass_filter(1000)

new1 = new.high_pass_filter(1000)

# increae volume by 6 dB
song_6_db_quieter = new1 + 6

# save the output
song_6_db_quieter.export("C://Users//User//Desktop//second.mp3", "mp3")
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple amplification can also be done easily with [`librosa`](https://librosa.org/):

```py
import librosa
import soundfile as sf

data, sr = librosa.load("input.wav")
factor = 0.5
data *= factor
sf.write("output.wav", data, sr)
```

Noise reduction is a more complicated problem. Simpler approaches include low and high-pass filtering, but it generally depends heavily on the characteristics of your signal and the noise.