# Sound volume in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have some project that need to play sound which can volume it up

```
import playsound
    playsound.playsound(PathToFile)
```

How can i volume up my sound with playsound library

Or i should use other library ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329617/change-the-volume-of-a-wav-file-in-python

Comment: @GwendalGrelier i don't want to create new file ,but i want something like this : first play sound with 10dB  second is 20dB and third is 30dB

Answer (score 3):

There isn't much of a documentation for playsound module, but here is how you could do it with pygame

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(thepath)
sound.set_volume(0.9)   # Now plays at 90% of full volume.
sound.play()
```

i got this from pygame official website, you can check it too for more info, [pygame website](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html).

Comment: I try to add this pygame.mixer.init(44100,-16,2,2048) to my first line and it's not error anymore ,but when i run my file i can't here the sound .I don't know what is 44100,-16,2,2048

Comment: 44100 is the frequency, -16 is the size, 2 is the channel, and 2048 is the buffer.

Comment: is it a *wav file

Comment: Yes,it is . now i can play sound ,but i can't volume it up

Comment: try setting the new volume before playing the sound

Comment: ALSA lib pcm.c:7963:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred  << it shows on my output

Comment: @EHM Can you use pygame to control the volume of individual speaker (of a headset), such that at one point the volume from the right speaker is 100% and the volume of the left speaker is 50%?